# ln -s command failing in Solaris

Tags: solaris, ln

I have a situation where my installation process runs a script which creates symbolic links for couple of files. The case here is the links are not being created and ln -s command is getting failed with the below error.

```
 No such file or directory
```

Where as the required files exits in the given location. I tried running the ln -s command from command prompt, which is working perfectly fine. What could be the cause.? Any thoughts?

Comment: Solaris `ln -s` works the same way whether it is called from the CLI or a script. The cause is then more than likely some bug in the latter. You should post your code to help us figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: Are you issuing the parameters out of order? It should be:  ln -s <existing file to link to> <new link>

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ln -sf
```

using also the absolute path for the source and destination

Regards
Claudio

Comment: It didn't help Claudio. :(

Comment: What about posting your script? We have no crystal ball to guess what is wrong with it.

Comment: yes please, posting your script it's the faster way to help you!

Comment: Mandou bem, garoto!